# G35 speaker, soldering

Tags: sound, repair

my G35 fell off the table and one of the speaker and the connecting cable got loose (right side). I glued all the plastic parts and opened it up to solder the cable.
My question is: which cable (A and B) goes where (1-4) (see picture)?
[image]

It's my first time repairing my own hardware.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open up the left side and check. It will most likely be pads 1 and 4 but the colours don't really tell you anything meaningful. You can only tell by seeing how the left side is wired and to replicate that.

Also be aware that the type of wire you are working with will have an insulating coating (coloured) which it will be necessary to burn off before you can solder. Some soldering irons will get to the right heat so that the coating melts away, so make sure your iron is hot enough or the solder will not tin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the information you gave me. I opened the left side: https://imgur.com/a/HgAPZMK
I am very inexperienced and have no idea if that tells me anything at all.

Comment: This is sooo far off-topic, but... you need to look at how the other speaker itself is wired, not the driver board. Mark is right [he usually is ;) that it looks like 1 & 4, but you need to get the colours the right way round or it will sound weird [out of phase].

Comment: OK the imgur pic shows the speaker wires at the top. Follow them through to the driver and see where they are connected on the speaker driver. Then do the same on the other side.